# NodeJS Send data with ejs to <script>

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, ejs

I am trying to send data from my nodejs server with ejs to my html. But the problem is I cant read the variable inside my script.

Nodejs server:

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
  var alert = req.query.msg;

  // connect to your database
  mssql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var request = new mssql.Request();

    request.query(
      "SELECT startDate, endDate  from Reservations",
      function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        events = [];
        recordset.recordset.forEach((element) => {
          reserv = {};
          reserv.start = element.startDate;
          reserv.end = element.endDate;
          events.push(reserv);
        });
        res.render("index", {
          alert: alert,
          events: events,
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I need to read events inside my html with smth like this:
`var events = <%= events %>`

but I get console error that events doesn't exist. Any idea how can I fix this or how can I make it work different way?

I tried creating div and direct assigning but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this issue, I found solution that works for me.

```
                <script> var eventsC = []; </script>

            <% events.forEach((element) => {%>
            <script>
                reserv = {};
                reserv.start = "<%= element.start %>";
                reserv.end = "<%= element.end %>";
                eventsC.push(reserv)                    
            </script>
              <% }); %>
```